# Is it possible to retrieve the modified time of the iPhone contacts record?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

I want to ask a question about iPhone. Is it possible to retrieve the modification time from the iPhone contacts of each record? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find found the answer in the apple developer website.
[kABPersonModificationDateProperty]
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html.

Comment: I think you mean kABPersonModificationDateProperty.